# Yaml pipeline. How to swap connstrings in Builds with Console App

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, console-application

I built a console app with .Net Core 3.1.  I have it building using Yaml leaning heavily on the learn.microsoft.com documentation.  The release is pushing to the correct box.  But I have an appsettings.json file that has a conn string variable that is different between my TEST, QA and PROD regions.  I knew how to do this with the xml file transforms in .NET and MVC but I can't get this to work.  Any help would be great since I don't even know the term for what I am trying to do here.

How do you change the connectionstring in the appsettings.json based on a variable or do I have to create 3 branches each with settings and create 3 build and release pipelines?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try and not work?

Comment: Honestly the biggest issue is not knowing what I didn't know and what the names of the things I was looking for and needed a place to start.  Leveraging terms and examples from the below was enough to jumpstart and get me going on the right course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to push to different environments you usually

1. Have seperate release pipelines that trigger from different branches.
2. You have one release pipeline with different stages that need pre-approval to move to the next stage TEST -> QA -> PROD.

In both cases you will make use of **Stage**.

There you need to add a task named **"File transformation"**

[image]

In the File Format select JSON

[image]

Now, any variable found in the appsettings.json file will be replaced by the variables you set in the pipeline.

Be careful because nested variables like

```
{
   SerilogSettings: {
      BatchSize: 100
   }
}
```

need to be set with a "." instead like

*SerilogSettings.BatchSize*

Comment: Thank you.  This gives me enough to go on.  I wasn't aware of what I was looking for or what it was called.  This is perfect.  Thank you.